# Overriding get_queryset in Django UpdateView. Why is it asking for <pk> or <slug> when I am returning the right queryset?

Tags: django, django-class-based-views, django-1.5

Here is my view.

```
class ModelxUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Modelx
    template_name='template.html'
    form_class = ModelxFormSet

       def get_queryset(self):
           # query_set = super(ModelxUpdateView, self).get_queryset().filter(user=self.request.user)
           query_set = Modelx.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
           return query_set
```

The error that it's throwing is

> AttributeError: Generic detail view ModelxUpdateView must be called with either an >object pk or a slug.

Could someone also clarify if editing multiple models is allowed via UpdateView? I mean if I am going to return a queryset, it's going to update each of the objects in that queryset right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Could someone also clarify if editing multiple models is allowed via
>   UpdateView? I mean if I am going to return a queryset, it's going to
>   update each of the objects in that queryset right?

No, [`UpdateView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#updateview) is for a single object only.  It inherits from the [`SingleObjectMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin) which is why it needs a primary key to be passed in; as this primary key is used in the `get_object` method.

To do multiple object updates, try the `UpdatesWithInlines` view from the [`django-extra-views`](https://github.com/AndrewIngram/django-extra-views) app.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It certainly helped to know that UpdateView only supports single objects. I'll work some way to update multiple objects.